# how can i get re patterns as dynamic input in python?

Tags: python

I'm using **re** module in python for some regex operations .Its working fine when i have defined the pattern to be matched statically in a python program.

For example,

```
import re
s="hi can you help me out"
pattern=r'[a-z ]*' #pattern that takes space and lower case letters only
i= re.fullmatch(pattern,s) #to check the entire string
print(i.string)


output:
hi can you help me out
```

Now let me come to the problem i have faced is, if i tried to take the input pattern from user in run time it throws exception .Here the code

```
import re
s="hi can you help me out"
pattern=input("Enter pattern:")
i= re.fullmatch(pattern,s)
print(i.string)

output:
Enter pattern:r'[a-z]*'
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'string'
```

Hope someone help me to sort out this problem.

python version:3.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you enter? works fine for `Enter pattern:[a-z ]*` PS. notice the `r'`

Comment: The opening `r'` and closing `'` are not part of the pattern

Comment: because you entered `r'[a-z ]*'` as input not `[a-z ]*`

Comment: @GomathiMeena By any chance are you using Python 2.x?

Comment: @GomathiMeena show us the error

Comment: @GomathiMeena, you may consider accepting the answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to enter this part `[a-z ]*` without the `r` string prefix:

**Python 3.x**:

```
import re
s = "hi can you help me out"
pattern = input("Enter pattern:")
i = re.fullmatch(pattern,s)
print(i.string)
```

**Python 2.x**:

```
import re
s = "hi can you help me out"
pattern = raw_input("Enter pattern:")   # since input() in python2.x is the same eval(raw_input()) which would return an int
i = re.fullmatch(pattern,s)
print(i.string)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Enter pattern:[a-z ]*
hi can you help me out
```